# How can I do HyperParameter Tuning for PMML model in python?

Tags: python, machine-learning, random-forest, hyperparameters, pmml

I am creating a RandomForest PMML model using the following code in Python

```
from sklearn2pmml.pipeline import PMMLPipeline
from sklearn2pmml import sklearn2pmml
rf=RandomForestClassifier()
rf = PMMLPipeline([('random',rf)])
rf.fit(X_train, y_train)
sklearn2pmml(rf, "classification pmml file/random.pmml",with_repr=True)
```

and I am loading the saved RandomForest Model using the following code in Python

```
from pypmml import Model
rf = Model.fromFile('classification pmml file/random.pmml')
```

How can I do HyperParameter Tuning for this RandomForest PMML model in Python?

Answer (score 1):

You can do hyperparameter tuning as usual; there is no need to do anything special if the resulting tuned pipeline in converted to PMML representation using the [SkLearn2PMML](https://github.com/jpmml/sklearn2pmml) package.

In brief, if you're only tuning one estimator, then simply wrap it into `GridSearchCV` in place. For example:

```
pipeline = PMMLPipeline([
  ("tuned-rf", GridSearchCV(RandomForestClassifier(..), param_grid = {..}))
])
pipeline.fit(X, y)
```

If you're tuning multiple estimators, then you can treat `GridSearchCV` as a top-level workflow engine, and wrap the whole pipeline into it. The tuned pipeline can be obtained as the `GridSearchCV.best_estimator_` attribute afterwards:

```
pipeline = PMMLPipeline([
  ("rf", RandomForestClassifier(..))
])
gridsearch = GridSearchCV(pipeline, param_gird = {..})
gridsearch.fit(X, y)
pipeline = gridsearch.best_estimator_
```

For more details, see the following technical article: https://openscoring.io/blog/2019/12/25/converting_sklearn_gridsearchcv_pipeline_pmml/